# ERROR: access denied to perform action "list" on "role", access denied to perform action "read" on "role"

Tags: teleport

for a CI/CD pipeline, i need an image for connecting to my teleport cluster to use a bot, which i will a create. Therefore i have installed gravitational/teleport:12.4.11 (following this [link](https://goteleport.com/docs/ver/12.x/machine-id/getting-started/) ) with all required tools. The Log-in using `tsh login --proxy=myteleport.registry.com` works fine, but the following `tctl get users`or `tctl get roles  --format=text` throws `ERROR: access denied to perform action "list" on "role", access denied to perform action "read" on "role"`.
I highly appreciate any tips or suggestions you may give to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the user who logged in using the `tsh login` command does not have the necessary privileges to view a list of users or roles with `tctl`.

You can try adding a role that grants the required permissions. Here's an example of a role configuration `manage-users-and-roles.yaml`:

```
kind: role
metadata:
  description: role to manage users & roles 
  name: manage-users-and-roles
spec:
  allow:
    rules:
    - resources:
      - user
      - role
      - read
      verbs:
      - list
      - create
      - read
      - update
      - delete
  deny: {}
version: v4
```

Add this role to teleport :

```
tctl create -f manage-users-and-roles.yaml
```

And then link this role with your user :

```
tctl users update <your-username> --set-roles <existing-roles>,manage-users-and-roles
```

---

*Note that you should be connected on your teleport server with the admin user*

You can find more information about managing roles on teleport in their docs :

- https://goteleport.com/docs/access-controls/guides/role-templates/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion, however if running `tctl create -f roles.yml` results in ERROR: access denied to perform action "read" on "role". I'm also setting up teleport via a docker-compose.yml, but i'm not sure if and where to edit the role administration there...

Comment: Hi, if you're using docker-compose, then you need to execute your `tctl` command inside your container, try to exec into your container `docker exec -it <your-teleport-container-id> bash` and then you will have the administrative roles, hopefully it will work.
tctl doc : [link](https://goteleport.com/docs/ver/12.x/reference/cli/#tctl)

Comment: thanks, for the hints. Btw do you know how to make a longer usage of the gitlab-token because mine stops  as default after 30min? So first i use tctl create -f gitlab-token.yml, then tctl bots add g<bot-name> --roles=access --token=<token-name> --logins=root but the token stops as described after 30 min.